# which projection are best for large continents

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, gis-principle, optimization

which projections are best for large continents and mid-latitudes

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the types and quality of questions that can be asked here.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, in general, any projection you choose will have some shortfalls. It is inherent issues when dealing with projecting a 3-D object (world) onto a flat surface (2-D map). You need to decide what is the most important feature you want preserved.

Here is a portion of what the resource from Hunter College provides for large continents:

> For larger-scale maps, from continents to large countries, equidistant projections (equidistant in the sense of true scale along the meridians) are good at balancing shape and area distortion. Depending on your area of interest, you might use:
>   ·         Azimuthal Equidistant
>   ·         Equidistant Conic
>   ·         Plate Carrée

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hunter College in NYC provides a good breakdown and a good reference resource for choosing a projection, you can read up more [here](http://www.geo.hunter.cuny.edu/~jochen/gtech201/lectures/lec6concepts/map%20coordinate%20systems/how%20to%20choose%20a%20projection.htm)